# buildroot add packages with submodules

Tags: busybox, buildroot

buildroot supports to download packages from git repo. But my git repo contains submodules.

How to order buildroot to download package with submodule?

Comment: Why this question was downvoted?

Answer (score 12):

Since ~[July 2016](https://git.buildroot.org/buildroot/commit/docs/manual/adding-packages-generic.txt?id=02f0878078a037c4c76ab1e478dad67ce422a148) you can enable downloading of Submodules for a package.

This can be achieved with

```
LIBFOO_GIT_SUBMODULES = YES
```

in the .mk File.

Answer (score 3):

This is not supported today. In general, the submodules are used to fetch external libraries, and prefer to see them packaged as separate Buildroot packages.

That being said, if you provided a specific example, I could probably have a look and give a more specific answer.

Comment: This answer is outdated. See my answer below.